Cannot get linked data (ASP.NET Core)
I have a method that must get LocationServices and linked to it LocationServicePrices
Here are the entities:
LocationService:
[Table("LocationService")]
public class LocationService : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }

    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual UnitOfMeasure UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LocationServicePrice> LocationServicePrices { get; set; }
}

And LocationServicePrice:
[Table("LocationServicePrice")]
public class LocationServicePrice : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int LocationServiceId { get; set; }
    public int PricingTierId { get; set; }

    public decimal? PricePerUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual LocationService LocationService { get; set; }
    public virtual PricingTier PricingTier { get; set; }
}

I try to get it like this
public async Task<LocationServiceEditDto> GetLocationServiceForEdit(NullableIdDto input)
{
    LocationServiceEditDto locationServiceEditDto;

    if (input.Id.HasValue)
    {
        locationServiceEditDto = await _locationServiceRepository.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.LocationServicePrices)
                .Where(x => x.Id == input.Id)
                .Select(x => new LocationServiceEditDto()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    TenantId = x.TenantId,
                    ServiceId = x.ServiceId,
                    LocationId = x.LocationId,
                    Cost = x.Cost,
                    MaterialUomId = x.UnitOfMeasureId,
                    MaterialUomName = x.UnitOfMeasure.Name,
                    Location = x.Location == null
                        ? null
                        : new LocationNameDto { Name = x.Location.Name },
                    LocationServicePrices = x.LocationServicePrices
                        .Select(price => new LocationServicePriceDto()
                        {
                            Id = price.Id,
                            LocationServiceId = price.LocationServiceId,
                            PricePerUnit = price.PricePerUnit,
                            PricingTierName = price.PricingTier.Name,
                            PricingTierId = price.PricingTierId
                        }).ToList()
                })
                .FirstAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        locationServiceEditDto = new LocationServiceEditDto();
    }

    return locationServiceEditDto;
}

But I have a collection that has zero items.
But if we can see from database, LocationService with Id = 32:

has 5 service prices:

How I can fix this?

Remove .FirstAsync() and see if you get missing items.  I think you need to GroupBy using the ID.  Then you need a SelectMany to get each item of the Group.

What is the returned value of _locationServiceRepository.GetAll()? Can you show the implementation?

public abstract IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()  in interface Abp. Domain. Repositories.IRepository<TEntity,TPrimaryKey>
It's a method of asp.net boilerplate
@YongShun

@jdweng I deleted FirstAsync and still didn't get data

Remove the methods .Include(x => x.LocationServicePrices) and .GetAll(). Up to the point of FirstOrDefaultAsync, you should have an IQueryable, and your Include() seems unnecessary because you are making the request in Select entirely.

without GetAll() Where can't work. So I need to left it @pashagoroshko

Use AsQueryable() instead of GetAll(), or the Include() should be before GetAll().

Based on what I read the document here, you should apply the [ForeignKey("LocationServiceId")] to LocationService and after that run the  migration. I think would be great if you can share the migration file for LocationServicePrice entity. Besides, try to check your DB table (LocationServicePrice), does the foreign key relationship created?

It seems that this is an EF problem. Why tag only asp.net and asp.net core? Like, you evidently know your trouble is with getting things from the database, how is that asp’s concern?

Can you show generated SQL?
